# Why image is not showing up in facebook share?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-social-plugins, socialshare

Why image is not showing up in facebook share?
Here is my code, please tell me where I have done wrong
my code is in localhost

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '1474558775911287',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.8'
    });
    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
  };

(function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>

  <title>Your Website Title</title>
  <meta property="og:url"         content="http://pypolo.com/" />
  <meta property="og:type"        content="website" />
  <meta property="og:title"       content="Hello" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="Your description" />
  <meta property="og:image"    content="http://avnavu.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/Usay-Mein-Yaad-Aata-Hoon-shayari.jpg" />
<!-- You can use Open Graph tags to customize link previews.
Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters -->
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>

  <!-- Your share button code -->
  <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="http://pypolo.com/" data-layout="button_count">
  </div>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by _“my code is in localhost”_? You are trying to share `http://pypolo.com/`, how is that your localhost? Is this not a real domain, but something you have just set up locally for testing? // You can not debug Open Graph meta tags from localhost - to read them, Facebook needs to request the page, and that is not possible via localhost.

Comment: I am testing it from localhost, basically http://pypolo.com/ is live

Comment: It may be live, but it doesn’t contain any Open Graph meta tags.

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with what the Facebook share button sees, try using the Sharing Debugger tool here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing

I tried entering the URL you put in there: http://pypolo.com

It will show you results of Facebooks's crawler when it looks at your meta tags. Apparently your **og:image** is not set on that domain.

You say that your code is running on your localhost. Facebook can't read from your computer at all. Also, your share button in the code is pointing to http://pypolo.com and not your machine. Even if you did try to point it to your machine, you'd have to have your machine setup basically like a real life server and open it to the world. Not something you typically want to do. So basically what I'm saying is that although you have the **og:image** in your code, that is not being sent at all to Facebook through the Facebook share button.

What you'll need to do is upload your code to the server that pypolo.com is running on. This way Facebook's crawler can see that image. Then retry the URL in the Sharing Debugger and you should see the image in the post at that point.